# Phonegap won't compile

Tags: android, cordova, compilation

I had a working phonegap project which I compiled using

> phonegap build android

And then aligned and signed using ant

> ant release

However, I had to format my computer, saved the folder on another drive, and copied it back after formatting. I installed jdk, android sdk, phonegap, ant, and when I try to compile it again (using the same command as before) I'm getting this error (which doesn't help at all, not even with --verbose):

> [error] An error occurred while building the android project.

What do I need to do to be able to compile the project again? Also, do you recommend using an IDE instead of the phonegap CLI?

Comment: try to run %userprofile%\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\check_reqs.bat if you're on windows or $home/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/check_reqs if you're on linux/osx (replace 3.3.0 with 3.4.0 if you're using cordova 3.4) and it should tell you what's missing

Comment: Nothing seems to be missing -> "Looks like your environment fully supports cordova-android development!"

Comment: You can check targetsdk in AndroidManifest.xml and check if you have installed the matching sdk api in android sdk manager

Comment: instead of `phonegap build android` try to run directly `platforms\android\cordova\build.bat` maybe it will display more info about the error.

Comment: That was it, I thought I had installed the correct API version but it seems I didn't, thanks QuickFix!